# Calculating limit in parts. Why possible?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, exponentiation

Let $f$, continuous function, differentiable at $x=1$ and $f(1)>0$.

Consider the following equation:

$$\lim \limits_{x\to 1} \left(\frac{\color{Blue}{f(x)-f(1)}(x-1)}{\color{Blue}{(x-1)}f(1)}\right)^\frac{1}{\log x} = \lim \limits_{x\to 1} \left( \frac{\color {Blue}{f'(1)}(x-1)}{f(1)} \right)^\frac{1}{\log x}$$

My question is: Why can you evaluate the blue expression on the LHS as $f'(1)$ **before** taking the limit? Moreover, the whole expression is powered by $\frac{1}{\log x}$

It seems to me like claiming $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^n = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(1+0)^n = 1$$

So what's making the first valid whereas the second is nonsense.

Comment: Maybe it is a coincidence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This: $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} f(x)^{g(x)}=(\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x))^{\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}g(x)}$$
only if both limits exist (in the narrow sense)! On the second example the outer limit $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n=\infty$, therefore doesn't exist (in the narrow sense).
In your first example I think it should be $$\frac{\textbf ( f(x)-f(1)\textbf{)}(x-1)}{(x-1)f(1)}$$ inside the brackets..

Comment: That property holds only if both limits exist AND $f(x)>0$ when $x$ tends to $\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is not a satisfying way to see that the equality holds (and I hope that the following is correct), but:

Let $$y = \left(\frac{\color{Blue}{[f(x)-f(1)]}(x-1)}{\color{Blue}{(x-1)}f(1)}\right)^\frac{1}{\ln x},$$ then

$$
\ln(y) = \frac{1}{\ln(x)}\ln\left(\frac{\color{Blue}{[f(x)-f(1)]}(x-1)}{\color{Blue}{(x-1)}f(1)}\right).
$$
Now
$$
\lim_{x\to 1} \left(\frac{\color{Blue}{[f(x)-f(1)]}(x-1)}{\color{Blue}{(x-1)}f(1)}\right) = \lim_{x\to 1} \frac{\color{Blue}{[f(x)-f(1)]}}{\color{Blue}{(x-1)}}\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{x-1}{f(1)} = 0,
$$
so
$$
\lim_{x\to 1} \ln\left(\frac{\color{Blue}{[f(x)-f(1)]}(x-1)}{\color{Blue}{(x-1)}f(1)}\right) = -\infty.
$$
Therefore
$$
\lim_{x\to 1} \ln(y) = -\infty.
$$
(You naturally might convince yourself that the right hand limit and the left hand limit indeed both are equal to this.

This shows that the limit of the left hand side is $0$.

Likewise 
$$
\lim_{x\to 1}\left( \frac{\color {Blue}{f'(1)}(x-1)}{f(1)} \right)^\frac{1}{\ln x} = 0.
$$

Comment: What you wrote is correct and useful, but this is not what was asked: "Why can you evaluate the blue expression on the LHS as $f′(1)$ **before** taking the limit?". We can't always evaluate a limit within a limit, but here it seems to work correctly; why?

Comment: @CareBear: I guess my point is that the two sides of the equality are equal. It doesn't necessarily matter how you get that they are equal. When you have a rule saying that you can "do something" all it means is that two expressions are *equal*. So in this case you can "evaluate" by taking the limit of $\frac{f(x) - f(1)}{x-1}$ as $x$ approaches $1$. My argument, of course, doesn't extend to other cases. The comment above for the other answer suggests that one, in fact, doesn't have a general rule for this.